# Error: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', or 'enum' Typescript multiplying value between array

Tags: angular, typescript

Typescript. I can't get rid of this error `The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts(2362)`

there was a problem when multiplying values inside the array. was trying to make a function to calculate cosine similarity with this code:

```
cosineSim(Q: string[], B: string[]){
    //var dotproduct = 0;
    let dotproduct: number= 0;
    var mA = 0;
    var mB = 0;
    for(var i=0; i< Q.length;i++){
      //The error goes here at Q[i] and B[i]
      //it says: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts
      dotproduct += Q[i] * B[i];
      mA += (Q[i] * Q[i]);
      mB += (B[i] * B[i]);
    }
    mA = Math.sqrt(mA);
    mB = Math.sqrt(mB);
    var similarity = (dotproduct) / ((mA) * (mB));
    return similarity;
  }
```

What I pass in another function like this code:

```
var cos1 = this.cosineSim(eachdocTFIDF[0], eachdocTFIDF[1]);
console.log(cos1);
```

Sample of the data:

```
//example value
eachdocTFIDF[0] = [0.5, 0.01123, 0, 0, 0.693215];
eachdocTFIDF[1] = [0.342131, 0.786785, 0, 0.2345, 0.00123];
```

Comment: Your type annotations say these are `string` arrays. If they're supposed to be `number` arrays, write that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function cosineSim(Q: number[], B: number[]){
//var dotproduct = 0;
let dotproduct: number= 0;
var mA = 0;
var mB = 0;
for(var i=0; i< Q.length;i++){
  //The error goes here at Q[i] and B[i]
  //it says: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.ts
  dotproduct += Q[i] * B[i];
  mA += (Q[i] * Q[i]);
  mB += (B[i] * B[i]);
}
mA = Math.sqrt(mA);
mB = Math.sqrt(mB);
var similarity = (dotproduct) / ((mA) * (mB));
return similarity;
```

}

Comment: You had a compilation error